# Docomo (now Airtel) Indian Prepaid sim card is in Grace State

Tags: international-travel, cellphones

I have been living in Europe last 5 years and had my Indian phone number active (which I use to receive the OTP for bank transactions).

Now after 5 years of usage, on my Indian number, I get a notification that the SIM card is in GRACE STATE.

What is Grace State.? 
Does it mean the SIM is close to de-activation?

How to retain this number? 
Has anyone got through this type of notification? 
Any tips, please!

Comment: Did you contact your service provider and ask them?

Comment: Tried searching online for more information on this. But no luck. Reaching the service provider would be like hunting a duck in the dark. Afraid of ending up in the queue on International roaming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sharing this update (it might help someone else in my situation)

As per the network provider, they deduct a very nominal charge every month for the not using the sim card (incoming or outgoing calls). Eventually, if the balance is lower than minimum balance, they warn using this code "GRACE STATE"

I solved the situation by recharging the number with 1000 Rs, and whenever it goes lower than allowed, have to repeat it again.

Answer (score 0):

Recharge with ₹ 35 every month and your problem will be solved... Its a new rule imposed forcefully by trai to Recharge monthly with this minimum amount

Comment: What is *by trai*?

Comment: TRAI - Telecom Regulatory Authority of India